# Tor Browser with custom proxy instead of Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, socks, proxy

I appreciate the Tor Browser's privacy features, but I don't want to run my data through the tor network. Instead I have a socks5 proxy I'd like to use.

I've tried disabling the TorLauncher addon, which allows me to use TorBrowser normally without a proxy.  If I try to add my proxy however, I get the "Unable to find the proxy server" error page.

If I use the same exact proxy settings in a normal Firefox browser, the connection works.

Is there some sort of hidden setting specific to TorBrowser that's causing this behavior?  Alternatively, is it possible to replicate TorBrowser's privacy settings in a normal Firefox instance?(afaik TorButton is no longer released separately)

Comment: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking

Answer (score 1):

Use [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/). Tor Browser is a Firefox, so it will fit